# Widgets don't show in my custom blogger template

Tags: html, xml, blogger

I'm creating my own blogger template. I don't have any experience. And since blogger doesn't provide any docs, I started to copy from other professional theme. I copied this section and saved it. But nothing is showing. This is the section code:

```xml
<b:section class='main-logo' id='main-logo' maxwidgets='1' name='Header Logo' showaddelement='yes'>
  <b:widget id='Image1' locked='false' title='' type='Image' version='2' visible='true'>
    <b:widget-settings>
      <b:widget-setting name='displayUrl'>https://i.ibb.co/kDvnmB5/image.png</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='displayHeight'>145</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='sectionWidth'>1076</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='shrinkToFit'>false</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='displayWidth'>734</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='link'/>
      <b:widget-setting name='caption'/>
    </b:widget-settings>
    <b:includable id='main'>
      <h4>From #Main</h4>
    </b:includable>
    <b:includable id='content'>
      <h4>From #Content</h4>
      <div class='widget-content'>
        <b:tag cond='data:link'  expr:href='data:link' name='a'>
          <img expr:alt='data:title' expr:height='data:height' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_img&quot;' expr:src='data:sourceUrl' expr:width='data:width'>
            <b:attr cond='data:sourceSet' expr:value='data:sourceSet' name='srcset'/>
          </img>
        </b:tag>
        <br/>
        <b:if cond='data:caption'>
          <span class='caption'><data:caption/></span>
        </b:if>
      </div>
    </b:includable>
  </b:widget>
</b:section>
```

To experiment, I added those 2 h4 tags. But Only output from that section I see is:

```html
<div class='main-logo no-items section' id='main-logo' name='Header Logo'></div>
```

Let me know if you have any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't in the code. It was in blogger layout. I debugged over 4 hours and found that blogger doesn't show widget when the amount of `<b:section>` is 1. Blogger requires more than 1 `<b:section/>` to display any widget. So, I solved the problem by adding a dummy section [`<b:section id='randomID90'/>`] in the template and everything works fine! Thanks to @Suramuthu R for giving me the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

Remove these three lines:

```
<b:includable id='main'>
  <h4>From #Main</h4>
</b:includable>
```

Comment: I removed it and saved. But nothing happened. Then I saw blogger automatically added `<b:includable id='main'>
  <b:include name='widget-title'/>
  <b:include name='content'/>
</b:includable>` this code.

Comment: I tested the above code in the blogger with ((i.e the includable tag and without includable tag). It didn't show the image first and it showed  the image after removal. Did you get a prompt saying whether you want to revert the template. And did you click 'yes' to that? If that were the case, there could be someother problem apart from this. copy your template in MsWord or libreoffice Writer document and send to my email id: suramuthurs@gmail.com.  I'll help. [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/75yuN9j)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. But I didn’t face any prompt while saving the template. Anyways, I sent the email containing the template. Thanks again!☺️

Comment: @SMShahriarZarir, I've replied to your email.